# Change random generated word after function is executed

Tags: javascript, html, function, random

I am currently working on a programme where you like or dislike a activity that is displayed on the screen. My problem: I would like the randomly generated word to change after either the thumbs down input is clicked or thumbs up input is clicked.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
let words = ['Food', 'Video Games', 'Movies', 'Spa', 'Sleeping'];
let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;

function ai(){
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "";
}

function aii(){
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h1 id="word"></h1>
<h1 id="liked"></h1>
<h1 id="disliked"></h1>
<input type="image" src="thumbsup.png" class="tu" onclick="ai()">
<input type="image" src="thumbsdown.png" class="td" onclick="aii()">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the random generation into the functions. You can create a function which does the random generation and then call that function inside your onclick functions

```js
let words = ['Food', 'Video Games', 'Movies', 'Spa', 'Sleeping'];

function random_generate(){
  let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;

}
function ai(){
  random_generate();
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "";
}

function aii(){
  random_generate();
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="word"></h1>
<h1 id="liked"></h1>
<h1 id="disliked"></h1>
<input type="image" src="thumbsup.png" class="tu" onclick="ai()">
<input type="image" src="thumbsdown.png" class="td" onclick="aii()">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just make the generation of the random word into a function,

```
function generate_random() {
  let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;   
}
```

And then call this function at the start of your script or in your constructor (depending on what framework you're using) and then just add the function call in your ai() and aii()

```
function ai(){
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "";
  generate_random();
}

function aii(){
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "";
  generate_random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are picking a random word only on declaration and just changing the text `onClick`.

You should create a function to pick the random word `onClick`, something like this:

```
const pickWord = () => words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

function ai(){
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = pickWord();
}
```